# declaring a variable blocks my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

is something wrong here?
declaring those variables stops the execution of my code :(

```
var color = $('fieldset input[type=checkbox]').data("color");
        if(color === orange){var bgy = '-1'}
        else{var bgy = '-37'};
```

If you need more info please ask me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean `color=='orange'`?

If it didn't help please alert the value of `color`.

Answer (score 1):

Dude... whats `orange` in

```
if(color === orange){var bgy = '-1'}
```

Use firebug :D

Comment: .data("color"); gets "orange"

Answer (score 0):

Define bgy outside the if block and just set the value inside.

Comment: That is better practice but it's probably not the cause of the error, since the if block doesn't have scope any var declarations are hoisted to the top of the current function. Any value set to bgy in the if/else blocks will be available to the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that should work fine...only thing I'd suggest is this:

```
var bgy;
var color = $('fieldset input[type=checkbox]').data("color");
if(color === 'orange'){ bgy = '-1' } else { bgy = '-37' };
```

Make sure jQuery's actually finding your element, and alert out the value of `color` to troubleshoot. Other than that, I'll need more code to go on...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use

`if(color === 'orange')`

other wise

`orange` will be treated as variable which is undefined.